# Responsive layout not resizing in FireFox

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, window-resize

I've searched on this website and others and can't seem to find a definitive answer. I'm creating a responsive email. Yes, i have done my research etc and i'm only here to seek help on an aspect that I know would be simple to someone who knows exactly how this all works.I've even contacted ZURB where I obtained this template from and so far no avail.

It is a responsive issue and i'm not sure if its due to the version of Firefox i'm using or that something is wrong with my code...? I have placed 100% width on each table (just in case thats the culprit) and its only the header that moves accordingly.

I queried if it was the CSS but it works in Safari. I'd appreciate the help and to see what the issue is.

Thanks- code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
/* ------------------------------------- 
        GLOBAL 
------------------------------------- */
* { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
* { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Helvetica", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

img { 
    max-width: 100%; 
}
.collapse {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
    -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; 
    width: 100%!important; 
    height: 100%;
}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        ELEMENTS 
------------------------------------- */
a { color: #0166b1;}

.btn {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #666;
    padding:10px 16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-right:10px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.callout {
    padding:15px;
    background-color:#ECF8FF;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.callout a {
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #0166b1;
}

table.social {
/*  padding:15px; */
    background-color: #ebebeb;

}
.social .soc-btn {
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #FFF;font-weight:bold;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
a.fb { background-color: #3B5998!important; }
a.tw { background-color: #1daced!important; }
a.gp { background-color: #DB4A39!important; }
a.ms { background-color: #000!important; }

.sidebar .soc-btn { 
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}

p.topNote { border-top: 4px solid #1b3281; margin-top:-2px;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        HEADER 
------------------------------------- */
table.head-wrap { width: 100%;}

.header.container table td.logo { padding: 15px; }
.header.container table td.label { padding: 15px; padding-left:0px;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        BODY 
------------------------------------- */
table.body-wrap { width: 100%;}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        FOOTER 
------------------------------------- */
table.footer-wrap { width: 100%;    clear:both!important;
}
.footer-wrap .container td.content  p { border-top: 1px solid rgb(215,215,215); padding-top:15px;}
.footer-wrap .container td.content p {
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight: bold;

}


/* ------------------------------------- 
        TYPOGRAPHY 
------------------------------------- */
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; line-height: 1.1; margin-bottom:15px; color:#000;
}
h1 small, h2 small, h3 small, h4 small, h5 small, h6 small { font-size: 60%; color: #6f6f6f; line-height: 0; text-transform: none; }

h1 { font-weight:bold; font-size: 30px; color:#1b3180;}
h2 { font-weight:200; font-size: 27px;}
h3 { font-weight:500; font-size: 22px; color:#0166b1;}
h4 { font-weight:500; font-size: 20px;}
h5 { font-weight:900; font-size: 17px;}
h6 { font-weight:900; font-size: 14px; text-transform: uppercase; color:#444;}

.collapse { margin:0!important;}


p, ul { 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-size:14px; 
    line-height:1.2;
}
p.lead { font-size:17px; }
p.last { margin-bottom:0px;}

ul li {
    margin-left:5px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

/* ------------------------------------- 
        SIDEBAR 
------------------------------------- */
ul.sidebar {
    background:#ebebeb;
    display:block;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ul.sidebar li { display: block; margin:0;}
ul.sidebar li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #666;
    padding:10px 16px;
/*  font-weight:bold; */
    margin-right:10px;
/*  text-align:center; */
    cursor:pointer;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777777;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    display:block;
    margin:0;
}
ul.sidebar li a.last { border-bottom-width:0px;}
ul.sidebar li a h1,ul.sidebar li a h2,ul.sidebar li a h3,ul.sidebar li a h4,ul.sidebar li a h5,ul.sidebar li a h6,ul.sidebar li a p { margin-bottom:0!important;}



/* --------------------------------------------------- 
        RESPONSIVENESS
        Nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure. 
------------------------------------------------------ */

/* Set a max-width, and make it display as block so it will automatically stretch to that width, but will also shrink down on a phone or something */
.container {
    display:block!important;
    max-width:640px!important;
    margin:0 auto!important; /* makes it centered */
    clear:both!important;
}

/* This should also be a block element, so that it will fill 100% of the .container */
.content {
    padding:15px;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block; 
}

.panelcontent {
    padding:15px;
    max-width:600px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block; 
}

/* Let's make sure tables in the content area are 100% wide */
.content table { width: 100%; }


/* Odds and ends */
.column {
    width: 300px;
    float:left;
}
.column tr td { padding: 15px; }
.column-wrap { 
    padding:0!important; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    max-width:600px!important;
}
.column table { width:100%;}
.social .column {
    width: 280px;
    min-width: 279px;
    float:left;
}

/* Be sure to place a .clear element after each set of columns, just to be safe */
.clear { display: block; clear: both; }


/* ------------------------------------------- 
        PHONE
        For clients that support media queries.
        Nothing fancy. 
-------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }

}



</style>
<!-- If you delete this tag, the sky will fall on your head -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Crystal Template</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/email.css" />

</head>

<body bgcolor="#ececec">

<!-- HEADER -->
<table class="head-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="header container">

                <div class="content">
                    <table bgcolor="#999999">
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/200x50/" /></td>
                        <td align="right"><h6 class="collapse">Hero</h6></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /HEADER -->


<!-- BODY -->
<table class="body-wrap"  width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

            <div class="content" width="100%">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- A Real Hero (and a real human being) -->
                        <p><img src="http://placehold.it/600x300" /></p><!-- /hero -->
                        <p class="topNote"></p>
                        <!-- Callout Panel -->
                        <h1>Welcome Mr Smith,</h1>
                        <p class="callout">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
                        </p><!-- /Callout Panel -->

                        <h3>Subheader 1</h3>

                        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et.</p>

                    <!--   panel content   -->            
                        <div class="panelcontent">
                    <table bgcolor="#cad9e4"  width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:10px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Title Ipsum <small>This is a note.</small></h4>
                            <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                            <a class="btn">Clickity Click &raquo;</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div><!-- panel content -->
        <!--   panel contentcad9e4   -->            

                <div class="panelcontent">
                <table bgcolor="#cad9e4"  width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="small" width="20%" style="vertical-align: top; padding-right:10px;"><img src="http://placehold.it/75x75" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Title Ipsum <small>This is a note.</small></h4>
                            <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. </p>
                            <a class="btn">Clickity Click &raquo;</a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div><!-- /panel content -->


                        <!-- Callout Panel -->
                        <!--<p class="callout">
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt. <a href="#">Do it Now! &raquo;</a>
                        </p>--><!-- /Callout Panel -->

                        <h3>Title Ipsum <small>This is a note.</small></h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        <a class="btn">Click Me!</a>

                        <br/>
                        <br/>                           

                        <!-- social & contact -->
                        <table class="social" width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <!--- column 1 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                

                                                <h5 class="">Connect with Us:</h5>
                                                <p class=""><a href="#" class="soc-btn fb">Facebook</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn tw">Twitter</a> <a href="#" class="soc-btn gp">Google+</a></p>


                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><!-- /column 1 -->  

                                    <!--- column 2 -->
                                    <table align="left" class="column"  width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>                

                                                <h5 class="">Contact Info:</h5>                                             
                                                <p>Phone: <strong>408.341.0600</strong><br/>
                Email: <strong><a href="emailto:hseldon@trantor.com">hseldon@trantor.com</a></strong></p>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table><!-- /column 2 -->

                                    <span class="clear"></span> 

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table><!-- /social & contact -->


                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /BODY -->

<!-- FOOTER -->
<table class="footer-wrap"  width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="container">

                <!-- content -->
                <div class="content">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <p>
                            <a href="#">Terms</a> |
                            <a href="#">Privacy</a> |
                            <a href="#"><unsubscribe>Unsubscribe</unsubscribe></a>
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                </div><!-- /content -->

        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- /FOOTER -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 600x300 image prevents the body to shrink. Make the width of this image flexible and it will work.

Add this in the media query block.

```
.container img { width:100% !important; }
```

It will make the image flex.

**Your old media query.**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }

}
```

**Media query with the flexible image**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    a[class="btn"] { display:block!important; margin-bottom:10px!important; background-image:none!important; margin-right:0!important;}

    div[class="column"] { width: auto!important; float:none!important;}

    table.social div[class="column"] {
        width:auto!important;
    }

    /* flex the image */
    .container img {width:100% !important;}

}
```